# How to search words that contain more than three of the same letter through out the entire word

Tags: c++

For some reason this code is printing out all the words in my list, while I want it to just print out words with more than three z's

I've managed to solve the code, below its searching for words that that have "zz" in them, an example buzz or blizzard. My main goal is to search for words that three z's through out the entire word an example off the top of my head would be zblizzard or something.

```
Word* Dictionary::findzs()
{
    int wordIndex = 0;
    cout << "List : " << endl;
    while (wordIndex < MAX_WORDS) {
        string word1 = myWords[wordIndex]->word;
        wordIndex++;
        if (word1.find("zz") != std::string::npos){
            cout << word1 << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

update:

```
bool has_3_zs(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::count(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 'z') >= 3;
}

void Dictionary::has3zs()
{
    int wordIndex = 0;
    string word = myWords[wordIndex]->word;
    while (wordIndex < MAX_WORDS) {
        for (auto& s : { word })
        {
            if (has_3_zs(s))
            {
                std::cout << s << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems:

1. `string::find_first_of()` is not the right function to use. It searches the string for the first character that matches **any** of the characters specified in its argument. In other words, your code does indeed look for a single letter `z` (since that's the only distinct letter that appears in `subString`). If you wish to find three `z`'s *in a row*, use `string::find()` instead. If you wish to find three `z`'s *anywhere in the string*, use `std::count()`.
2. Your are not checking the return value correctly. You are implicitly comparing the return value to zero, whereas you need to be comparing against `string::npos`.
3. The `wordIndex++` is misplaced.
4. `return myWords[wordIndex]` looks like out-of-bounds access, potentially resulting in [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Hayde `if(word1.find("zzz") != std::string::npos) // found` [Look at the example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: @BoBTFish Hey I added it but now its not printing out anything, I had a look at some examples but don't know whats wrong.

Comment: Note that string::find() will look for the sub-string "zzz" in the searched string. If you expect words such as zeBeztInzeWorld to be "found" - then find will not do that! find will only "find" words such as "Buzzz" or "Buzzzzzz" or "Buzzzt". Nor will you find "BuZZZ" as its Z's are uppercase.

Comment: @AviPerel: Very good points, thanks. I interpreted the question as talking about three `z`'s *in a row*, but perhaps that's not what the OP is after.

Comment: @AviPerel What type of function would be ideal, to find a word like zeBeztInzeWorld. I think I have it working now my dictionary doesn't have any words with "zzz" hence why it's not listing anything. But my goal is to find words that have three z's through out the entire word, not together.

Comment: I'm starting to think you want [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). (Although there could be a slightly more efficient version that stops iterating the string once it hits 3, I don't think we really care in this case. Simplicity is a big plus.)

Comment: Using `std::count` would I use this to count the letter three times and then print the results?

Answer (score 3):

I get it now. You want to match strings that contain a least 3 `'z'` characters anywhere.

Use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). This example:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::count
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end
#include <string>    // std::string

// This is the function you care about.
// It returns `true` if the string has at least 3 'z's.
bool has_3_zs (const std::string& s)
{
    return std::count(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 'z') >= 3;
}

// This is just a test case. Ignore the way I write my loop.
int main()
{
    for (auto& s : {"Hello", "zWorzldz", "Another", "zStzzring"} )
    {
        if (has_3_zs(s))
        {
            std::cout << s << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
zWorzldz
zStzzring
```

**Edit**:

Ok, I've written an example a bit more like yours. My loop is written roughly the same way as yours (which in my opinion is not the best, but I don't want to add further confusion).

```
// This is the function you care about.
// It returns `true` if the string has at least 3 'z's.
bool has_3_zs (const std::string& s)
{
    return std::count(std::begin(s), std::end(s), 'z') >= 3;
}

struct SomeTypeWithAWord
{
    std::string word; // The bit you care about

    // Allow me to easily make these for my example
    SomeTypeWithAWord(char const * c) : word(c) {}
};

// This will contain the words.
// Don't worry about how I fill it up,
// I've just written it the shortest way I know how.
std::vector<SomeTypeWithAWord> myWords
                                {"Hello", "zWorzldz", "Another", "zStzzring"};

// This is the function you are trying to write.
// It loops over `myWords` and prints any with 3 or more 'z's.
void findzs()
{
    std::cout << "List : \n";
    std::vector<SomeTypeWithAWord>::size_type wordIndex = 0;
    while (wordIndex < myWords.size()) // Loop over all the words
    {
        const std::string& testWord = myWords[wordIndex].word;
        if (has_3_zs(testWord)) // Test each individual word
        {
            std::cout << testWord << '\n'; // Print it
        }
        ++wordIndex;
    }
}

int main()
{
    findzs();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a crack, seems to be what my goal is.

Comment: @Hayde Not really relevant to this question, but may I ask if you [really meant to use `endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/)?

Comment: Yea, I think I've used it a bit too much, when its not needed. I plan to tidy it up, Regarding your piece of code, how could I implement my list of words which is myWords[wordIndex] I tried adding them but it's giving and error too many arguments in function call

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What have you written?

Comment: I added it to my first post, check it out.

Comment: Ok. Just ignore my `main`. If you are not familiar with range-based `for` (the way I wrote my loop) don't worry about it right now. Just use whatever idiom you are comfortable with for looping over a container (looks like a `std::vector`?) and use my function on each element to decide whether to print it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT- BoB TFish is the simpler, hence better solution.

You may use find_first_of 3 times to see if you have (at least) 3 z's spread throughout the word.
Try something like this:

```
Word* Dictionary::findzs()
    {
        int wordIndex = 0;
        cout << "List : " << endl;
        size_t where;
        int i;
        string subString = "z"; // or "zZ" if you want uppercase as well
        while (wordIndex < MAX_WORDS) {
            string word1 = myWords[wordIndex]->word;
            where  = 0;
            for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
            {
              where =  word1.find_first_of(substring, where);
              if (where == string::npos)
                   break;
              where++; // fix...
            }

            if (i == 3)
            {
                cout << word1 << endl;
            }

            wordIndex++;
        }
        //return myWords[wordIndex]; - this will try to return myWords[MAX_WORDS] which is probably outside array bounds
       return NULL; // or whatever else you see fit

    }
```

Comment: Hey I had a look at this, put it's listing all words with z, is that normal.

Comment: You're right, need to increment "where" to skip the 'z' already found. see //fix...